# Getting Fixed IP for Hosting FireBase function or Google APP Engine

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to get Fixed IP for Hosting FireBase function or Google APP Engine Instance.

I am hosting a Node Js Function